# Passing data from view to controller using Smarty template

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I downloaded an application and it is written using **SMARTY TEMPLATE ENGINE**. I am trying to create a search engine with drop down suggestion.

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{$_L['Search']}" id="txtsearch">

<div id="filter"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $( "#txtsearch" ).keyup(function() {
  if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 0){  
  filter = document.getElementById('filter').style.display="block";  

  userInput = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("txtsearch").value);  

 var _url = $("#_url").val();
 var urlsuggest = _url + 'ps/auto-suggest?userInput='+userInput;

  xmlHttp.open("GET", urlsuggest, true);  

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;  
  xmlHttp.send(null);  
  }else{  
  } 
});
```

**Controller**

```
  if(isset($_GET['userInput'])){
   $value = $_GET['userInput']; //assign the value
  }else{
   echo "no input";
  }

  $getdata = ORM::for_table('sys_items')->where_like('name',"%$value%")->order_by_asc('name')->find_many();
```

The problem is that the `$value` variable in the Controller is not getting the value which is passed in the `var urlsuggest`in the java script. When i add a default value in the `$value` variable for example `$value="PRC"` and change the var urlsuggest to `_url + 'ps/auto-suggest'` the code works fine and it will show all the data with the word "PRC" in the filter div.

How can i pass the value of the input field to the `$value` variable in my Controller? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use rawurldecode() because you are encoding with encodeURIComponent.
See the [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php)